# Recent Posts Change Headline Date

Tags: wordpress, date, posts

I am trying to change the date when you click on the Calendar and get a post come up.

At the moment Headline is Y,m,d (2012 December 20) I want to change it to l, F j, Y to (Thursday, December 20, 2012).

Which PHP Wordpress file do i manipulate to make this change?

Cheers

John

Answer (score 0):

please do one thing just replace function twentyeleven_posted_on() with below function in functions.php
hope it will give you the date format which you require.

```
function twentyeleven_posted_on() {
    printf( __( '<span class="sep">Posted on </span><a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s">%4$s</time></a><span class="by-author"> <span class="sep"> by </span> <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%5$s" title="%6$s" rel="author">%7$s</a></span></span>', 'twentyeleven' ),
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'l, F j, Y' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'twentyeleven' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        get_the_author()
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi there Praveen kalal  Thank you for your message.  I need to ask a question before making the change.  Should this not be done in the Theme I am using and not the tweentyeleven theme?

Comment: Ok do one thing just replace get_the_date() and get_comment_date() with get_the_date('l, F j, Y') and get_comment_date('l, F j, Y') in functions.php where above functions being call.